# How to request my free database backup that is scheduled for deletion?

Tags: heroku

I missed the notifications that Heroku would start deleting their free Postgres databases. I want to start paying for my account, but my Postgres add-on is removed from my app. There's a message saying that:

> As of November 28th, 2022, free Heroku Postgres and Heroku Data for Redis® plans are no longer available. If you used these resources, and want to recover your data, contact Heroku Support as soon as possible.

However, as my plan is free, I can't send a support ticket. Where can I request a backup of my DB?

Thanks.

Comment: I would like a support for an issue like this also.